# Best practices/howto concerning users in security context

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to symfony and I wonder if someone could explain to me how handling users with a login is done. I have a class User with 3 Subclasses (Admin, Editor, Noob) that extend the User. Those users can log in on the front page and, depending on what kind of user they are, they can see various pages. 
For example: There is a "change password" page, where passwords for the users can be changed. Admins and Editors can access all of these, but the Noob is only allowed to change his own password. So I made the route in security.yml available for all three roles:

```
- { path: ^/user/changepw, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_NOOB }
```

Within the changepwAction I must now check if the user is a Noob and, if so, whether the current UserId is his own. I wonder: how do I do this? I will need to check these things in various controllers where users will only have access to some IDs. What I started with looked something like this:

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
$loggedInUser = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
//if Noob (ID 3)
if($loggedInUser->getUserGroup()->getId() == 3) { ... }
```

This seems highly impractical to me, if I have to add usergroups later on, I will have to search through each controller to edit these parts. I was thinking maybe I could create some globally available function checkUserRights($action, $options) in which I fetch the currentlyLoggedInUser and check against $action ("changepw" in this case) and maybe some additional parameters $options if the user is allowed to use this action. Is that a good idea and if so - how do I make checkUserRights globally available?

If not - how else could this be done? I'd be thankful for any hints.

Comment: Checkin it in each controllers is not a solution. As a hint, research about "Listeners", actually you need an authentication listener http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html

Comment: could you explain in detail how I would use an authentication listener to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Create a service (YourBundle\Resources\config\config.xml or services.xml)

```
<service id="mycustom.security.interactive_login_listener" class="UserBundle\Security\InteractiveLoginListener">
    <argument type="service" id="service1" />
    <argument type="service" id="service2" />
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.interactive_login" method="onSecurityInteractiveLogin" priority="1" />
</service>
```

Create your listener (YourBundle\Security\InteractiveLoginListener):

```
class InteractiveLoginListener
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //constructor    
    }

    /**
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        /** @var User $user */

        if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
            // do something    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing that, but it seems to me that onSecurityInteractiveLogin is called only when a user is logging in - I don't see how this solves my problem in changepwAction

Comment: Try this, custom events http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html

Comment: Can you please add examples of file paths? We don't know where to copy and paste this code.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used a Voter to do this. So I could do something like $securityContext->isGranted('USER_EDIT_PROFILES', $user)

I'm not sure though if this was the best solution, in fact it seems like I should have done it differently:

[Symfony - use voter in entityRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958771/symfony-use-voter-in-entityrepository)