# Symfony - use voter in entityRepository

Tags: php, symfony

My problem is this: I have a page /user which shows a list of all users. The page is visible only to those who are logged in and, depending on what kind of user the currently logged in user is, he sees only parts of the list. 
I figured that a voter would be a good solution to this (if there's a better one please let me know), but I have a problem with supportsClass. 
The userlist is a query in UserRepository named getAllUsers and I tried passing the securityContext to the repository so I can query if the current user has access or not. 
My action looks like this:

```
    public function listAction($limit = 50, $offset = 0) {
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $userRepository = $manager->getRepository('SeamUserBundle:User');
        $users = $userRepository->getAllUsers($this->get('security.context'));
        return ....
    }
```

and in userRepository I tried this:

```
public function getAllUsers($securityContext) {
    ....         
    if(!$securityContext->isGranted('USER_LIST_ALL', null)) {
       //modify query
    }
    ...
}
```

but if I pass null as a second parameter to isGranted, the $class is now the Voter and therefore supportsClass returns false. 
Am I doing this the wrong way? If so - how do I do this? If not - what's missing? How do I pass the user entity to isGranted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using roles? i.e.: ROLE_USER_LIST_ALL (you define it in symfony and add to user) and hen in your userRepository you call $securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER_LIST_ALL');

edit: As side note I wouldn't pass securityContext as argument for get* but I would set it with setSecurityContext using service definition.

Comment: Basically what @Jundra said.  You would normally use a voter to test access to a specific object.  In your case, you are trying to query only accessible objects.  So basically, you just test for roles.  The alternative is to query all your users then test each individual user to determine if it is accessible.  Of course, loading all users might have a bit of a performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grant permission on global basis you want to use [roles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles) instead of [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html).

Diference between roles and voters:

**Voter** is there to tell *if user can perform action on object* (relation user-action-instance_of_object). Logic behind voters is up to you. You need to implement them and symfony only finds voters and collects their decision. Example: User can edit specific instance of article.

**Role** is there to tell *if user has global permission* (relation user-action). Logic behind roles is handled by symfony. You only add roles to user and require roles on $securityContext. Example: user can write new article.

Listing all users is based on what user can do hence it is job for role. You need to add role `ROLE_USER_LIST_ALL` to users that are allowed to list all users. You should probably do that in UserProvider when user is logging in. All you need to do is as [UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html) requires implement getRoles. Some information about defining roles in database can be found in [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database)

Then in your `UserRepository` call

```
$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER_LIST_ALL');
```

Notice there is not second parameter because it is global permission not related to specific object instances.

Also it isn't ideal to pass security context as param for getter. Instead it might be good idea to specify repository as service and set security context.

```
services:
   seam.user.repository:
    class: Seam\UserBundle\UserRepository
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments:
      - Seam\UserBundle\User
    calls:
      - [ setSecurityContext, [@security.context] ]
```

Then you can retrieve it with

```
$container->get('seam.user.repository); 
//in controler use $this instead of $container
```

(You need to implemenet `setSecurityContext` in your `UserRepository` class)